# Devise does not valdiate email while sign_up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-token-auth, ivalidatableobject

I have a model, User:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :trackable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
  extend EncryptedField

  validates :email, uniqueness: true, allow_nil: true
  validates :mobile,
    presence: true,
    uniqueness: true,
    phone: { possible: false, types: [:mobile], allow_blank: false }
end
```

On sign_up on `postman`:

At route `localhost:3000/auth` with body:

```
{
    "first_name": "RaghJhu",
    "last_name": "Deesp",
    "mobile": "+91 9726544141",
    "answer": "Yes1",
    "email": "apoorewewewewdedgcom",
    "password": "Password@123#",
    "provider": "mobile",
    "password_confirmation": "Password@123#"
}
```

returns response User created.

`email` is not a required field.

I have also defined email_regexp in `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```rb
config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/
```

Can you tell me why it is not validating email?

Comment: remove   , allow_nil: true

Comment: I am unable to recreate this on Rails 7. From the code, it looks like this Rails app is quite old, and I am gonna guess that some behaviour of devise has changed. However, you can try writing a custom validation https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Answer (score 1):

please set below email validation:

```
validates_format_of :email, with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP
```

Comment: It makes email presence as required. I want to validate only if email is present.